# Getting the Paragraphs out of a txt-file without the empty lines

Tags: python

So, I have a Text-File and I want to print out just the Paragraphs of that File. My code seems to be working, but everytime when there is a empty line in the txt-file, my Output shows me "None". I understand it has something to do with the return statement, but I really dont get where my mistake is
Here is my Code:

```
class ByParagraph:
    def __init__(self,iterable):
        self.iterable = iterable
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        for line in self.iterable:
            if line.isspace():
                break
            else:
                return "".join(line.rstrip())
        else:
            raise StopIteration()




with open("example.txt") as f:
    for p in ByParagraph(f):
        print(p)
```

Here is the output:

```
None
This is an a sentence.
None
This is another sentence.
Followed by yet another one.
None
None
This is not the last sentence.
This one neither.
None
None
None
This one is the last one.
```

And it should look like this

```
This is an a sentence.
This is another sentence. Followed by yet another one.
This is not the last sentence. This one neither.
This one is the last one.
```

I was expecting to get an Output without the "none" Statements.

Comment: Note that the for loop in `__next__` never gets past a single iteration, since it unconditionally `return`s or `break`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter() function on text.splitlines() to remove empty lines and the result is joined back with newline separator:

```
lines = filter(lambda x: x.strip() != "", text.splitlines())
text = "\n".join(lines)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the __init__ function, you can add some logic to automatically remove empty lines, like so:

```
def __init__(self,iterable):
    iterable=iterable.split('\n')
    while '' in iterable:
       iterable.remove('')
    new_iterable=''
    for i in iterable:
        new_iterable+=i
    self.iterable=new_iterable+'\n'
```